# Why shouldn't we use pointer arithmetic with gsl::not_null?

Tags: c++, pointers, null, pointer-arithmetic, cpp-core-guidelines

This is a contrived example, but consider the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gsl.h"

int main(){

  //object or array that I'd like to iterate over one byte at a time
  char array[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f'};

  //create a C-like iterator
  char* it = &array[0];

  //use pointer arithmetic to process
  std::cout << *it << std::endl; it++;
  std::cout << *it << std::endl; it++;
  std::cout << *it << std::endl; it++;
}
```

For safety, I'd like to tag the pointer with `not_null`.
**However, this fails to compile.**

```
#include "gsl.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(){

  //object or array that I'd like to iterate over one byte at a time
  char array[] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f'};

  //create a C-like iterator
  gsl::not_null<char*> it = &array[0];

  //use pointer arithmetic to process
  std::cout << *it << std::endl; it++;
  std::cout << *it << std::endl; it++;
  std::cout << *it << std::endl; it++;
}
```

*An except from `not_null`'s class :*

```
// unwanted operators...pointers only point to single objects!
// TODO ensure all arithmetic ops on this type are unavailable
not_null<T>& operator++() = delete;
not_null<T>& operator--() = delete;
not_null<T> operator++(int) = delete;
not_null<T> operator--(int) = delete;
not_null<T>& operator+(size_t) = delete;
not_null<T>& operator+=(size_t) = delete;
not_null<T>& operator-(size_t) = delete;
not_null<T>& operator-=(size_t) = delete;
```

I'm confused as to why they've done this.
Why can't I have a pointer that changes its value?

Especially when it is easy to get around:

```
it = &array[0];
it = static_cast<char*>(it)+1;
```

Am I missing the point of `not_null`?
The [C++ Guidelines](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Ri-nullptr) don't cover why something like this would be a bad use case.

Comment: Presumably `not_null` is intended for single objects that can never be null under any circumstances. It's possible to compile time check that they not be null initially, but if pointer arithmetic were allowed, you couldn't guarantee they'd never be null. So they disallow pointer arithmetic, and in the process introduce a new guarantee, that the pointer can only be reassigned; the cast cheats here (reintroducing the possibility of null), but so be it.

Comment: you shouldn't use c idioms in C++, i'll just say it. Stick to plain char * arrays / pointers if you want to operate on them with `++`

Comment: @self: I'd consider the iterator protocol in C++ to be a formalization and generalization of pointer arithmetic, it's not particularly C specific.

Comment: The guidelines would probably prefer you to construct a `gsl::span` instead for the array and then use iterators from that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not allowed because a pointer is not an array. Yes, an array can *decay* into a pointer, but as the word suggests, such decay loses information. The resultant pointer is not equivalent to the array.

By contrast, converting an array into a `gsl::span` loses no information. The size of the array is maintained, as is the ability to iterate through it.

`not_null` is for a pointer to an object, not an array of objects. Just as `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` don't allow for pointer arithmetic. If you want to use pointer arithmetic to process an array, the correct answer is `gsl::span` and its iterators.